# Tag addition: something like [analog-front-end]/[afe] or [signal-conditioning]

Tags: discussion, tags

After encountering two questions([digital](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/327872/1), [analog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/231347/1)) that mis-use the [dc-dc-converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-dc-converter) tag and editing the analog question, I realized that there's not a tag for a very common EE task: have a signal of type X and need it in type Y to use it. Searching for the tags [analog-front-end](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analog-front-end), [afe](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afe), and [signal-conditioning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-conditioning) show 0 results on all of them at the time of posting.

Would it be valuable to add (any of) these tags to help organize questions from simple voltage scaling/shifting to precision thermocouple or high-bandwidth RF inputs?

Some related (if possibly near-duplicate) questions from the above analog question:

- [Interface a 5v pressure sensor with a 3.3v ADC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42572/interface-a-5v-pressure-sensor-with-a-3-3v-adc)
- [Converting 0 to 24V analog signal to 0 to 5V for ADC input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/converting-0-to-24v-analog-signal-to-0-to-5v-for-adc-input?rq=1)
- [Convert 10.5V to 15V into 0 - 3.3V range for adc input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98307/convert-10-5v-to-15v-into-0-3-3v-range-for-adc-input?rq=1)

Comment: Analog and and analog front end are synonymous in my book

Comment: @laptop2d can you add this as a full answer?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the board would benefit from [analog-front-end](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analog-front-end) and [signal-conditioning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-conditioning) tags,
in general.

The questions in the O.P. are analog scaling jobs  \$ v_2 = A v_1 + v_{offset} \$, where \$ v_1 \$, \$ A \$, \$ V_{offset} \$ aren't tough.  These aren't hard enough analog jobs to properly qualify as "signal conditioning" or "analog front end".

Let's find harder questions.

Comment: Oh, there are certainly better questions and these should probably get a one-question-fits-most replacement referencing using opamps.